# When GPO no longer applies, is deployed software automatically uninstalled?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy, msi

Are packages installed by GPO automatically removed when the GPO no longer applies?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you check the checkbox titled, "Uninstall this application when it falls out of the scope of management," on the Software Install policy it will uninstall.

Comment: I personally use this option by default.